# If the guy I'm speaking to wants to know wether there is a physical attraction what is he allowed to see of me in islam?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, women, hijab

I want to know how much he can see of me physically when we haven't done a nikah yet.We are speaking through text on a halal basis with our mom's in the group chat. Due to him being in another country (with the niyyah of moving) he hasn't yet seen me in person but he has seen pictures. As a niqabi from a practicing family I want to know exactly what he is allowed to see before nikah.